# Designing a asynchronous binary divider in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

What I need to do is create a divider that uses long division, without using a clock. My current code seems like it implements the algorithm correctly...but there's a problem. My outputs are not initialized; their values are always X. I'm not sure how to initialize wires (I thought you didn't have to?) I tried to use reg for the outputs, but it made things complicated with the for loop. What can I do?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns

module alu_div(dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder);
   input wire[31:0] dividend, divisor;
   output wire[31:0] quotient, remainder;

   genvar i;
   generate
   for (i = 31; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
       assign remainder = remainder << 1;
       assign remainder[0] = dividend[i];
       assign remainder = ((remainder >= divisor) ? (remainder - divisor):remainder);
       assign quotient[i] = ((remainder >= divisor) ? 1:quotient[i]);
  end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`assigns` are continuous assignments therefore the following make no sense:

```
assign remainder    = remainder << 1;
assign remainder[0] = dividend[i];
assign remainder    = ((remainder >= divisor) ? (remainder - divisor):remainder);
```

Your deleted question was much closer to what you needed. Generate statements are overkill for this situation.

```
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i = 31; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
    remainder   = remainder << 1;
    remainder[0] = dividend[i];
    remainder    = ((remainder >= divisor) ? (remainder - divisor):remainder);
    quotient[i]  = ((remainder >= divisor) ? 1:quotient[i]);
  end
end
```

What you will notice is that `remainder` gets overridden in each iteration of the loop. this probably needs to be turned into a memory (array) so each iteration gets its own value. This at least will aid debugging as you could see what is happening at each step.

```
reg [31:0] remainder [0:31];
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i = 31; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
    remainder[i]   = remainder[i] << 1;
    remainder[i][0] = dividend[i];
    remainder[i]    = ((remainder[i] >= divisor) ? (remainder[i] - divisor):remainder[i]);
    quotient[i]     = ((remainder[i] >= divisor) ? 1:quotient[i]);
  end
end
```